# Looking for javascript component with a syntax highlight

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-highlighting

There are some pretty good RTE HTML text editors(like jsredaktor, TinyMCE or FCK Editor), but I'm looking for html/javascript component, something like TEXTAREA but with a code syntax highlight.

Comment: StackOverlow is not a script finding service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out CodeMirror, I think by far the best available - http://codemirror.net/